# Pure Javascript insert text into <input type="text"> without attributes

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<div style="top: 0px; left: 0px;" class="uiInlineBlock uiMenuHolder">
 <div>
  <input type="text">
 </div>
</div>
```

To select the input element i have used:

`inputelement = document.getElementsByClassName('uiInlineBlock uiMenuHolder')[0].children[0].children[0];`

The problem is i am trying to put text inside the text area but by using value i set the value but the text field remains empty.
How can i fix this with pure javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and a cascading selectors to select the first div so the second and finally the input instead to select step by step starting from the external div:

- div.uiInlineBlock.uiMenuHolder select the first div
- div select the child div
- input[type=text] select the child input text field

So the full string 'div.uiInlineBlock.uiMenuHolder div input[type=text]' will select all input text fields inside a div contained in a div having the following two classes: uiInlineBlock uiMenuHolder.

Because the querySelectorAll will return a list and because in your case you have only one input you need to take the first element of the result.

```js
window.onload=function() {
  
  var inputEle = document.querySelectorAll('div.uiInlineBlock.uiMenuHolder div input[type=text]');
  
  inputEle[0].value = 'your value';
}
```

```html
<div style="top: 0px; left: 0px;" class="uiInlineBlock uiMenuHolder">
    <div>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

More safely

```
inputelement = document.querySelector('.uiInlineBlock.iMenuHolder input');

inputelement.value = 'your value';
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
inputelement = document.getElementsByClassName('uiInlineBlock uiMenuHolder')[0].children[0].children[0]

inputelement.value = 'your value';
```

```html
<div style="top: 0px; left: 0px;" class="uiInlineBlock uiMenuHolder">
 <div>
  <input type="text">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man! I thought that i have tried that but apparanety i have not.